# Ideal generated by union of ideals contains finite sums only

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I just read this unproven claim:
Let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of ideals of $R$, then the ideal generated by $\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i$ is given by the set
$$\left\{\sum_{i\in I} x_i\middle \vert x_i\in a_i, x_i=0\text{ for all but finitely many i}\right\}.$$
Why is it clear that the sums must be of finitely many elements?

Comment: How would they even be over infinitely many elements?

Comment: finite sums are closed under addition of two of them

Comment: That beast (i) is an ideal and (ii) contains each $a_i$, and (iii) each such finite sum must be in any ideal containing all $a_i$.

Comment: What is a "sum of infinitely many elements"?